# Dynamically add multiple key value pair in a json array in bash

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I am having the below json array and i wanted to append two additional key value pairs  in the json array using bash. This is need to add dynamically on my existing json array file. Can somebody share some ideas on fixing this?

json array file :

```
[
  {
   "entry": "10.20.15.0/24",
   "comment": "test ip1"
  },

  {
    "entry": "10.20.16.0/24",
    "comment": "test ip2"
  }
]
```

additional key value pair I wanted to append,

```
 {
   "entry": "10.20.17.0/24",
   "comment": "test ip3"
  },

  {
    "entry": "10.20.18.0/24",
    "comment": "test ip4"
  }
```

so the final json array should  look like as below,

```
[
  {
   "entry": "10.20.15.0/24",
   "comment": "test ip1"
  },

  {
    "entry": "10.20.16.0/24",
    "comment": "test ip2"
  },

  {
   "entry": "10.20.17.0/24",
   "comment": "test ip3"
  },

  {
    "entry": "10.20.18.0/24",
    "comment": "test ip4"
  }

]
```

Comment: The OP already tagged the question with [tag:jq].

Comment: What specific technical problem did you encounter that stopped you from doing this on your own?

Comment: (did you already know how to do it with one element but have a problem that only came up when trying to add multiple elements? If so, show what you already had, and show that problem -- that way you disambiguate the question from existing append-to-an-array-with-jq questions, of which there are many).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hardcoded records to add:

```sh
jq '
   . + [
      {
         "entry": "10.20.17.0/24",
         "comment": "test ip3"
      },
      {
         "entry": "10.20.18.0/24",
         "comment": "test ip4"
      }
   ]
' file.json
```

Records to add provided as an argument:

```sh
jq --argjson to_add '
   [
      {
         "entry": "10.20.17.0/24",
         "comment": "test ip3"
      },
      {
         "entry": "10.20.18.0/24",
         "comment": "test ip4"
      }
   ]
' '. + $to_add' file.json
```

Records to add provided as a file:

```sh
jq --argfile to_add to_add.json '. + $to_add' file.json
```

or

```sh
jq --slurp add file.json to_add.json
```

Comment: thanks, this helps to fix the issue.